# What should I use instead of void as one of the alternative types in an variant?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, monostate, std-variant

I want to have a variant which may contain type Foo, (disjoint) type Bar, or nothing. Well, naturally, I was thinking of using `std::variant<Foo, Bar, void>` - but this doesn't seem to work. That is, you can define this type, but if you try to instantiate this you'll fail (GCC 8.2).

So what do I use instead? Some kind of empty struct?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you really want is a type among the alternatives which has a *single* possible value - not `void`, which has *no* possible values (and is problematic in other ways). In other words: A [unit type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) instead of a [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type).

The standard library has defined, as part of `<variant>`, a "unit type" for this use case: [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) (and yes, it's essentially an empty struct). Use it.

Example:

```
#include <variant>

using Foo = int;
using Bar = double;

int main() {
    std::variant<std::monostate, Foo, Bar> v; 
    v = Foo{}; 
}
```

Note that, unlike in the question, the single-possible-value type is the *first* alternative; this allows the variant to be default-constructible even if `Foo` isn't. Also, it's potentially cheaper/faster to construct the variant this way than constructing a `Foo`, even if it is default-constructible.

Comment: `struct { };` as replacement of `void` is not that new.  New (for me) is that it got part of `std` library since C++17 (as `std::monostate`). ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean this offensive - just was surprised after I read about `std::monostate`. "Something or nothing" reminds me to `std::optional` but I believe the memory footprint of your `std::variant` is even lower (although this might depend from implementation details).

Comment: @Scheff: It's not "mine"... :-)  Also, I doubt the memory footprint of `std::variant<std::monotone, T>` is lower than `std::optional<T>`...

Comment: I once digged into code of `std::optional` (out of curiosity) and I believe it stores aside of pay-load whether it was constructed or not (but it's a while ago - I might fail). I assume, `std::variant` doesn't need such extra "admin", does it? Out of curiosity, I took _your_ `std::variant<std::monostate, Foo, Bar>` and compared it with _my_ alternative `std::optional<std::variant<Foo, Bar> >` which I wouldn't prefer: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f9bbc36471ae6f6). (I already disclaimed that implementations of `std` classes may differ.)

Comment: `std::variant` needs to store the index of which type currently occupies the variant (and to allow for no-type for the case of exceptions).

Comment: A, yepp. Therefore, the 16 bytes storage. I just was guessing why it needs more than 8 bytes assuming that 8 bytes would be sufficient for `int` as well as `double`. The `std::monostate` consumed 1 byte (I tested before). I once read that `sizeof (struct { })` may not be 0. The reason explained was that everything, which can have storage may not have 0 size (if I remember right).